# Download links given by YouTube API return 403

Tags: youtube

I am trying to download all available files that are different qualities of a single video using the YouTube API, but every URL I follow to download the video results in a 403.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

_video_info=$(wget -qO- -- "http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=$1&el=detailpage&ps=default&eurl=&gl=US&hl=en")
_video_urls=$(sed -e 's|%25|%|g' -e 's|%25|%|g' -e 's|%3A|:|g' -e 's|%2F|/|g' -e 's|%26|\&|g' -e 's|%3D|=|g' -e 's|%3F|?|g' -e 's|%2C|,|g' -e 's|%2B|+|g' -e 's|%3B|;|g' -e 's|%22|"|g' -e 's|.*url_encoded_fmt_stream_map=url=\(.*&itag=[0-9]*\).*|\1|' -e 's|,url=|\n|g' <<< "${_video_info}")
_video_formats=$(sed 's|.*fmt_list=\([^\&]*\)\&.*|\1|' <<< "${_video_info}")

while read -r _video_download_url; do
    wget "${_video_download_url}"
done <<< "${_video_urls}"
```

Output:

```
$ ./ytdl 5_xCfrpif4Q
--2011-08-19 00:14:21--  http://o-o.preferred.mil01s10.v1.lscache5.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?sparams=id,expire,ip,ipbits,itag,ratebypass&fexp=907312,904535,913501,906918&itag=43&ip=93.0.0.0&signature=32944F059B26E01072437068EAC6449FCD975383.2272568B833A7A706A82236297B6D6B8D900D330&sver=3&ratebypass=yes&expire=1313733600&key=yt1&ipbits=8&id=e7fc427eba627f84&quality=medium&fallback_host=tc.v1.cache5.c.youtube.com&type=video/webm;+codecs=%22vp8.0,+vorbis%22&itag=43
Resolving o-o.preferred.mil01s10.v1.lscache5.c.youtube.com... 173.194.2.38, 2a00:1450:4002:3::6
Connecting to o-o.preferred.mil01s10.v1.lscache5.c.youtube.com|173.194.2.38|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2011-08-19 00:14:22 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

--2011-08-19 00:14:22--  http://o-o.preferred.mil01s10.v15.lscache6.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?sparams=id,expire,ip,ipbits,itag,algorithm,burst,factor&fexp=907312,904535,913501,906918&algorithm=throttle-factor&itag=34&ip=93.0.0.0&burst=40&sver=3&signature=C623D3002F9BC919B8D83666DB1274D9E37F9B63.A6FF45792995744504C9DF39EDEE8326D74450C5&expire=1313733600&key=yt1&ipbits=8&factor=1.25&id=e7fc427eba627f84&quality=medium&fallback_host=tc.v15.cache6.c.youtube.com&type=video/x-flv&itag=34
Resolving o-o.preferred.mil01s10.v15.lscache6.c.youtube.com... 173.194.2.56, 2a00:1450:4002:3::18
Connecting to o-o.preferred.mil01s10.v15.lscache6.c.youtube.com|173.194.2.56|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2011-08-19 00:14:22 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

--2011-08-19 00:14:22--  http://o-o.preferred.mil01s10.v13.lscache5.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?sparams=id,expire,ip,ipbits,itag,ratebypass&fexp=907312,904535,913501,906918&itag=18&ip=93.0.0.0&signature=88D969809C0625D2B7AC600C0D0C127F7AD72022.CA5355DAEF26B2AADBD6AAFF1726A331C54850C0&sver=3&ratebypass=yes&expire=1313733600&key=yt1&ipbits=8&id=e7fc427eba627f84&quality=medium&fallback_host=tc.v13.cache5.c.youtube.com&type=video/mp4;+codecs=%22avc1.42001E,+mp4a.40.2%22&itag=18
Resolving o-o.preferred.mil01s10.v13.lscache5.c.youtube.com... 173.194.2.48, 2a00:1450:4002:3::10
Connecting to o-o.preferred.mil01s10.v13.lscache5.c.youtube.com|173.194.2.48|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2011-08-19 00:14:22 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

--2011-08-19 00:14:22--  http://o-o.preferred.mil01s10.v1.lscache8.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?sparams=id,expire,ip,ipbits,itag,algorithm,burst,factor&fexp=907312,904535,913501,906918&algorithm=throttle-factor&itag=5&ip=93.0.0.0&burst=40&sver=3&signature=2D1C0BD8F7B617691F9905E79502E1FFFFF86611.C19F9CC435873BBC955C5FF82F60F7B90D140AFD&expire=1313733600&key=yt1&ipbits=8&factor=1.25&id=e7fc427eba627f84&quality=small&fallback_host=tc.v1.cache8.c.youtube.com&type=video/x-flv&itag=5
Resolving o-o.preferred.mil01s10.v1.lscache8.c.youtube.com... 173.194.2.38, 2a00:1450:4002:3::6
Connecting to o-o.preferred.mil01s10.v1.lscache8.c.youtube.com|173.194.2.38|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2011-08-19 00:14:22 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

As you can see from the `wget` output, the URLs seem syntactically correct, but the servers always return a 403. This happens no matter which video I try.

I am trying to download the files from the same IP address and computer that I generated the links with. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried downloading videos that your channel has uploaded? Are you attempting to use an authenticated connection with Youtube?

Answer (score 1):

You're likely getting a `403` error due to not being authenticated via your `wget` command. Youtube only allows downloading videos that you own. For that you'll have to be authenticated.

[Youtube TOS](http://www.youtube.com/static?gl=US&template=terms)

[Youtube downloading Support](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=56100)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to study [this webpage](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2) carefully.

Don't forget that Youtube is a product invented by Google. Just like Google Map, you have got to obtain the API Key first